# Git: how to revert series of commits with one commit

Tags: git

In git, is it possible to revert series of commits with a single commit? I have the following history, from which I want to revert commits B and C

```
E (HEAD)
|
D
|
C
|
B
|
A
```

Can this be done with the `reset` command, as it's possible to revert *all* the following commits by hard resetting to target commit, and soft resetting back to head?

Comment: I think you are looking for rebase, not reset

Comment: No, I don't want to rewrite the history. I want to create a new commit, which undoes the changes introduced by the series of commits

Comment: That's called rewriting history. Take a look at interactive rebase

Comment: You're trying to squash some , discard others. That's what interactive rebase is for. Sorry , mobile

Comment: For me, rewriting history is losing some commits (or rewriting them). I don't considering adding a new commit reverting some changes as rewriting the history.

Answer (score 4):

You could revert multiple commits in separate commits and then squash them into one?

The real question here is why do you want to revert everything in a single commit - It would be much clearer to do them in separate commits in a single separate branch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `git revert -n` (on each commit to be backed-out) followed by `git commit`.  You'll get one big commit that has the effect of undoing multiple commits.  It's rarely a great idea, though: it is difficult to tell what got reverted and why.  (On the other hand, reverting many small commits is also rarely a great idea, so in some cases you must choose which method is least-bad.)